# Undefined control sequence \cite after using apacite

Tags: natbib

I tried using `apacite`, then decided it was too complex for me as a beginner, so I reverted to `natbib` and a plain bibliography style. But now `\cite` won't work anymore.

The displayed errors are:

> ```
> Undefined control sequence. \cite{Boeing}
> Missing number, treated as zero. \cite{Boeing}
> ```

I checked my bibliography and everything seems to be in order. But for what it's worth I'll put it in below along with the packages I'm using.

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{natbib}

\makenomenclature
```

`.bib` file

```
@misc{Boeing,
  author     = "Boeing",
  title  = "Boeing-787-Ultimate-Load-Wing-Test-Completed",
  url    = "http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/Boeing-787-Ultimate-Load-Wing-Test-Completed-2.jpg"
}

@misc{EFUNDA,
  author    = "Efunda",
  title     = "Strain Gage: Materials",
  url       = "http://www.efunda.com/designstandards/sensors/strain_gages/strain_gage_selection_matl.cfm"
}

@misc{IbeamCS,
  author     = "The Engineering Toolbox",
  title  = "American Wide Flange Steel Beams, Retrieved December 6, 2015, from ",
  url    = "http://docs.engineeringtoolbox.com/documents/1313/steel-beam.png"
}

@book{StrainGauge,
  title="Process control instrumentation technology",
  author="Johnson, Curtis D",
  year="1993",
  publisher="Prentice Hall PTR"
}   

@misc{Wheatstone,
  author = "All About Circuits",
  title  = "Chapter 9 - Electrical Instrumentation Signals - Strain Gauges, ",
  url      = "http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-9/strain-gauges/"    
}
```

Thanks for any and all input. I am using TeXStudio for the record. I also notice that in the `.aux` file this was appearing:

```
\bibcite{Boeing}{{1}{{\APACyear {{\bibnodate {}}}}}{{Boeing}}{{Boeing}}}
```

for each entry. Does this mean that the effects of apacite are still in order on my document?
Sorry if the format of this question is messy, I just started learnging latex and it is my first time here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I have edited your question a bit to make it more readable (code can be indented by four spaces to make it monospaced, inline code can be set in ```...```), I have also re-tagged it because it is evidently not about `biblatex`.

Comment: welcome to the site but it is very hard to help if you do not give code that reproduces the error, or show the error that tex gives. the error messages you quote are not in the format tex uses (and lack information to diagnose the problem) probably it is a summary view from your editor, it would help to see the actual error lines from the log file, in a code section so that line breaks are preserved

Comment: Have you tried deleting the temporary `.aux` file as well as the `.bbl`? If you switch packages the temporary files might contain stuff the new packages cannot deal with.

Comment: When switching from one bibliography and citation management package to another (here: from `apacite` to `natbib`), it's usually necessary to delete the `.aux` file and then re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and the LaTeX twice more. The reason for having to delete the `.aux` file is that the `apacite` package employs instructions, such as `\APACyear` and `\bibnodate`, which aren't recognized by `natbib`.

Comment: That's it. I deleted both files and it works! Thank you all so much and apologies for the atrocious formatting. I'll be sure to clean up my questions in future!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's solved in comments by deleting aux files.